# nodemon app crashed (without error) in production, works in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I am stumped by this problem...

I have this code

```js
const { sql, poolPromise } = require("../../pool");

router.get("/api/route", async (req, res) => {
    let query = `
        BIG ASS 300 LOC QUERY
    `
    try {
        const pool = await poolPromise;
        const request = await pool.request();

        let result = await request.query(query);

        let final = result.recordset;

        console.log(final);               // <------ this works! I get 80 mb of data

        res.send(final);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    } finally {
        sql.close();
    }
});
```

The query works for both locahost and production, as the results are logged in the console.

However, When I run this code in production, I get the `[nodemon] app crashed`

I get no errors in the console...

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with the code.

I updated nodejs and npm, and it worked fine. No idea why.